# How to change target blank in internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, html

```
<a href="brochure.pdf" target="_blank"  >Download as PDF</a>
```

target blank is not working in ie 8

Is there any solution to open a file in IE ??

Comment: No idea of what "not working" means exactly, but in my IE8 virtual machine it opens links in a new window.

Comment: As @ÁlvaroG.Vicario said atleast a new window will open even if the link is incorrect.I think the pdf is not opening,correct the path and it should open.If you insist on using the same code as above, ensure that your pdf file is in the same directory as your html file.

Comment: Why is this question upvoted??

Comment: PDF is in same directory..it is working fine in firefox..but having issue with ie 8

Comment: You should have mentioned that only IE is the culprit.

Comment: Sorry if my comment wasn't clear enough. What I mean is that I cannot reproduce. As far as I know, Microsoft did not remove support for `target="_blank"` in IE8. I hope you aren't asking about the ActiveX plug-in by Adobe.

Comment: I tried this on a virtual machine with IE8 and it worked fine. The window popping up caused a very short blink but eventually it asked me whether to open or save the file.

Answer (score 0):

To determine if your web browser can open a PDF from your local hard drive.

In your web browser, choose File > Open (or Open File).
(Windows only) From the Files Of Type menu, choose All Files.
Click Browse.
Locate a PDF on your computer, select it, and then click Open.

If the PDF opens, there is some other problem.If not follow the steps below:-

To configure the browser to use Acrobat or Adobe Reader to open PDF files:

1. Start Acrobat or Adobe Reader.
2. Choose Edit > Preferences.
3. Select Internet in the list on the left.
4. Select Display PDF in Browser, and click OK.
5. Start Internet Explorer

Src:http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/cant-view-pdf-web.html